# Limitation of Evaluate in Lotus script

Tags: operation, evaluate

I am using an evaluate statement to see if a field value contains another variable value. Both has multiple values.

Here is my code below:

macro = {users*=@Uppercase(@Explode("}& Join(recipient,",") &{";","))}
macroflag = Evaluate( macro, doc )

- "users" is an array of user names and have 20 values
- "recipient" is an array of user names and have 80 values
- All values doesn't have any special charaters

When evaluating, it throws error "Operation Failed."

When I reduce the names to 55 in recipient field, no issue. It pass through the evaluate.

Is there any limitation for Evaluate? Can enlighten any ideas?

Thanks & Regards
Suresh

Tried reducing the names to 55, works fine.